# Azure Cosmos DB with Kotlin (ktor) value of "com.azure.cosmos.models.CosmosItemResponse.getItem()" is null

Tags: azure, kotlin, azure-cosmosdb

Trying to create item in Cosmos (document) DB with Kotlin (Ktor)
using `implementation("com.azure:azure-cosmos:4.41.0")`

```
@Serializable
data class Session(
    var id: String? = null,
    var name: String,
    var city: String,
)
```

```
override suspend fun createSession(session: Session): Response? {
        try {
            session.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
            val response = sessionContainerRef.createItem(session)
            return Response (
                response.item.id!!,
                response.item.name
            )
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            throw(ex)
        }
    }
```

The code creates a record in DB but the item in response object is always null.
I get the error message:

> Cannot invoke "model.Session.getId()" because the return value of "com.azure.cosmos.models.CosmosItemResponse.getItem()" is null

What am I missing? How to fix this?
Thnx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CosmosClient contentResponseOnWriteEnabled flag should be set true, and consistencyLevel should be set as 'SESSION'. Following code snippet fixed my problem.

```
init {
        val client = CosmosClientBuilder()
            .endpoint(config.endpoint)
            .key(config.primaryKey)
            .consistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.SESSION)
            .contentResponseOnWriteEnabled(true)
            .buildClient();
    }
```